# UITableViewCell automatic height incorrect until I scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to display news articles in a `UITableView` in my `UIViewController` subclass (I need some other views inside it so that's why I'm not using `UITableViewController`)

The cells are supposed to be full width and automatic height.

The problem is that the visible cells don't have the correct height the first time they load and so they don't display correctly at all, they only become correctly sized after I scroll down (where other already correctly sized cells are) and back up.

I tried adding various combinations of `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, `updateConstraints`, `layoutSubviews`, `layoutIfNeeded` and other similar methods to both the UITableView and the cells but it never had any effect at all.

I'd greatly appreciate any help, as I've been trying to fix this for a long time now and never came up with a solution.

## My setup

I have custom cells of type `MyStoryCell` which is stored in a .xib file:

[MyStoryCell.xib in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNtEF.png)

Its class looks like this:

```
class MyStoryCell: UITableViewCell
{
    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var badgeView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var taglineLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - Methods
    func setTaglineText(text: String)
    {
        ....
    }

    func setTitleText(text: String)
    {
        ...
    }

    // MARK: - Overrides
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let image = self.thumbnailView?.image
        {
            // Using PureLayout
            self.thumbnailView?.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: (self.contentView.frame.width * image.size.height / image.size.width))
        }
    }
}
```

The view controller (function `fetchTableData`) pulls a number of articles from web, stores them in an array (`currentStories`) and then adds them all to the UITableView using:

```
self.table.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

In the view controller's `viewDidLoad` override I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setting up table view
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    table.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyStoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "StoryCell")

    // Setting cells to automatic height
    table.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    // ... some more code

    fetchTableData()
}
```

My table view functions are:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return currentStories.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: MyStoryCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MyStoryCell
    if cell == nil
    {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyStoryCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "StoryCell")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MyStoryCell
    }

    if currentStories.count >= indexPath.row + 1
    {
        let currentStory: Story = currentStories[indexPath.row]

        dispatch_async(get_user_queue()) {
            let badgeImage = codeToFetchBadgeImage

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell?.badgeView.image = badgeImage
            })

            let thumbnailImage = codeToFetchThumbnailImage

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell?.thumbnailView.image = thumbnailImage
            })
        }

        // Set labels
        cell?.dateLabel.text = currentStory.storyDate
        cell?.setTitleText(currentStory.storyTitle) // Attributed string
        cell?.setTaglineText(currentStory.storyTagline) // Attributed string
    }

    return cell!
}
```

fetchTableData implementation:

```
func fetchTableData()
{
    /* removed unnecessary code for displaying loading indicator etc. */
    stories = [Story]()
    currentStories = [Story]()

    table.reloadData()

    // Go through all the feeds
    for feed in 0...rss_urls.count-1
    {
        // Set url of the RSS feed
        var rss_url: NSURL = rss_urls[feed]

        // Try to download the RSS feed
        if var rss_data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: rss_url)
        {
            // Initialize the XML Parser and set its delegate to self
            parser = NSXMLParser(data: rss_data)
            parser.delegate = self

            // Start parsing XML
            parser.parse()
        }
        else
        {
            alert_rss_error_show()
        }
    }

    // Sort by ID
    stories.sort{ $0.storyId.toInt() > $1.storyId.toInt() }
}

class DataManager {
    func requestData(offset:Int, size:Int, array:[Story], listener:([Story]) -> ()) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            //generate items
            var arr:[Story] = []
            var limit = offset + size
            if limit >= stories.count
            {
                limit = stories.count - 1
            }
            if offset > limit
            {
                allLoaded = true
                return
            }
            // For each story
            for i in offset...limit {

                // Story for current index
                var currentStory: Story = stories[i]

                if let badgeUrl = currentStory.storyBadgeUrl
                {
                    if !badgeUrl.isEmpty
                    {
                        if let currentBadge = badgeCache[badgeUrl] { }
                        else
                        {
                            if let badgeData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: badgeUrl)!)
                            {
                                var image = UIImage(data: badgeData)
                                badgeCache[badgeUrl] = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // If story has a thumbnail stored in cache, skip the next step
                if let currentThumbnail = thumbnailCache[currentStory.storyLink] { }
                else if !currentStory.storyThumbLink.isEmpty
                {
                    if let thumbnailData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: currentStory.storyThumbLink)!)
                    {
                        var image = UIImage(data: thumbnailData)
                        thumbnailCache[currentStory.storyLink] = image
                    }
                }
                arr.append(currentStory)
            }

            //call listener in main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                listener(arr)
            }
        }
    }

    loadSegment(0, size: PageSize)
}

func loadSegment(offset:Int, size:Int) {
    if (!self.isLoading) {
        self.isLoading = true

        let manager = DataManager()
        manager.requestData(offset, size: size, array: currentStories,
            listener: {(items:[Story]) -> () in
                for item in items {
                    var row = currentStories.count
                    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row,inSection:0)
                    currentStories.append(item)
                    self.table.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
                }
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show fetchTableData() implementation.

Comment: @GaneshKamath added it as requested

Comment: Cool, Jan Bureš. Did you try calling reloadData in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @GaneshKamath I did, but nothing changed. I think the problem is that the thumbnails are loaded asynchronously, but don't know what to do about this issue

Comment: Yes. If you had image dimensions (or the aspect ratio) in the data that you fetch to show in the table, you could solve this problem.

Comment: @GaneshKamath Yeah I thought that would be the case. Oh well, I guess it'll do without exact  size images, I'll just use an approximate aspect ratio. Thanks for looking into this for me, though!

Comment: Yeah, use an approximate aspect ratio and set the contentMode of the image view to ScaleAspectFill and clipsToBounds of the image view to true.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function from the UITableViewDelegate protocol to your table view functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 300.0
}
```

Your table view is asking you for each cell what is the height you want. If you don't reply it will use the one from the NIB file.

For more information about these functions you can check the Apple documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have made it clearer; I need the cells to have automatic height. Also when I set the return value of this function to UITableViewAutomaticDimension, it does the same thing - I have to scroll down and back up in order for the layout to update

Comment: @JanBureš do you mean the autolayout inside the cell and not the cell size? Is the cell size correct?